# Node Shortcut or BAT

Tags: node.js, batch-file, shortcut

I am tired of manually typing the path and run in the command prompt.

Here is what I need:

1. Run Command Prompt
2. `cd c:\socket\nodejs`
3. Execute `node test.js`

How can I create a BAT or shortcut for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a shortcut that creates a `cmd` window and with its working directory set to `c:\socket\nodejs`. Keep the window open during development. You can also copy the shortcut into your startup directory so the window will open when you log in.

Comment: Thank you.
But It is only half solved.
Target:
%COMSPEC%
Start in:
"%c:\socket\nodejs%

I still have to type  node test.js   Can I make it run the command after it has opened the cmd ?

Comment: Hm.. this is not working very well.. I cant pin it to the taskbar, because when I move it, it changes the directory

Comment: Well you could certainly add `node test.js` as arguments to `cmd`, but then your window will close when/if your code exits, losing any error or debugging messages. You could always create a batch file with a single-letter name if you want to save typing (e.g. you could just type "n" at the command prompt).

Comment: Oh, and ditch the percent signs around your starting directory: it's a literal, not a variable.